# Get frequency from Android mic

Tags: java, android, fft, android-audiorecord

I know that this question was asked, but it has no distinct answer.
So, what I've found is some example here : [FFT spectrum analysis](https://github.com/sommukhopadhyay/FFTBasedSpectrumAnalyzer)
Where I can transform my array of doubles with FFT class

```
RealDoubleFFT transformer;
int blockSize= */2048;
short[] buffer = new short[blockSize];
double[] toTransform = new double[blockSize];
         bufferReadResult = audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, blockSize);

                            for (int i = 0; i < blockSize && i < bufferReadResult; i++) {
                                toTransform[i] = (double) buffer[i] / 32768.0; // signed 16 bit
                            }

                            transformer.ft(toTransform);
```

so now I don't know how to get a frequency

I wrote such method :

```
public static int calculateFFTFrequency(double[] audioData){
    float  sampleRate = 44100;
    int numSamples = audioData.length;
    double max = Double.MIN_VALUE;
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i< numSamples -1; i++){
        if (audioData[i] > max) {
            max = audioData[i];
            index = i;
        }
    }
    float freq = (sampleRate / (float) numSamples * (float) index) * 2F;
    return (int)freq;
}
```

I try to implement a formula, but it doesn't return me anything good - some wild numbers

I tried zero passing as well :

```
 public static int calculateFrequency(short [] audioData){

        int sampleRate = 44100;
        int numSamples = audioData.length;
        int numCrossing = 0;
        for (int p = 0; p < numSamples-1; p++)
        {
            if ((audioData[p] > 0 && audioData[p + 1] <= 0) ||
                    (audioData[p] < 0 && audioData[p + 1] >= 0))
            {
                numCrossing++;
            }
        }

        float numSecondsRecorded = (float)numSamples/(float)sampleRate;
        float numCycles = numCrossing/2;
        float frequency = numCycles/numSecondsRecorded;

        return (int)frequency;
    }
```

But in zero passing method if I play "A" note on piano it shows me 430 for a moment (which is close to A) and then start to show some wild numbers when the sound fades - 800+ , 1000+ , etc.

Can somebody help me how to get more or less actual frequency from the mic?

Answer (score 0):

You should test your solution using a generated stream rather than a mic, then testing if the frequency detected is what you expect. Then you can do real life tests with mic, you should analyze the data collected by mic by yourself in case of any issues. There could be non audible sounds in your environment that could cause some strange results. When the sound fades there could be some harmonical sounds and these harmonicals can become lauder than the base sound. There's a lot of things to be considered when processing sounds from real environment.

Comment: but I want to create a tuner - I need a mic :)

Answer (score 0):

What you hear from a piano is a pitch, not just a spectral frequency. They are not the same thing.  Pitch is a psycho-acoustic phenomena, depending more on periodicity, not just the spectral peak.  A bare FFT reports spectral frequency magnitudes, which can be composed of overtones, harmonics, and other artifacts, and may or may not include the fundamental pitch frequency.

So what you may want to use instead of an FFT is a pitch detection/estimation algorithm, which is a bit more complicated than just picking a peak magnitude out of an FFT.